# Make single ActiveRecord query through several associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following models and associations:

```
class Organization
  has_many :buildings
end
class Building
  has_many :counters
end
class Counter
  has_many :counter_records
end
class CounterRecord
  belongs_to :counter
end
```

I would like to get something like this

```
organization.counter_records(dimension_day: start_date...end_date)
```

(`[dimension_day: start_date...end_date]` - it's condition).

How do I get counters records of `organization` through all these models?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into [Activerecord Querying guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).

Specifically you're interested in [`joins`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-joins):

```
Organization.joins(buildings: { counters: :counter_records })
            .where(counter_records: { dimension_day: start_date...end_date })
            .group('organizations.id')
```

You can create a method:

```
class Organization
  def filter_counter_records(start_date, end_date)
    self.class
        .where(id: id)
        .joins(buildings: { counters: :counter_records })
        .where(counter_records: { dimension_day: start_date...end_date })
        .group('organizations.id')
  end
end
```

Now the following is possible:

```
organization = Organization.first
organization.filter_counter_records(start_date, end_date)
```

---

But more idiomatic/conventional option would be using associations:

```
class Organization
  has_many :buildings
  has_many :counters,        through: :buildings
  has_many :counter_records, through: :counters
end
```

Now you can just go with

```
organization = Organization.first
organization.counter_records.where(dimension_day: start_date..end_date)
```

The last step here would be setting up the [`scope`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods.html#method-i-scope) in `CounterRecord`:

```
class CounterRecord
  scope :by_date_range, ->(start_date, end_date) { where(dimension_day: start_date..end_date) }
end
```

And now

```
organization = Organization.first
organization.counter_records.by_date_range(start_date, end_date)
```